# Speedtest-CLI output for monitoring

Tags: ubuntu, awk, performance, monitoring

So I'm pretty new to Linux and I really can't figure it how to.

So I wanted to make a useful output for our monitoring Tool with `speedtest-cli`. We have to monitor download and upload speeds for multiple locations.

I made following script that breaks the output with awk and gives me the desired number (in this case only the number itself without text in front and behind the number)

```
SP=$(speedtest-cli 2>&1)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
Down=$(echo $SP | gawk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[3]}' | \
                  gawk '{split($0,a," "); print a[1]}')
fi 
echo "$Down"
```

This script works as I want it to. But, I really would like a solution to return only the digits. So is it possible to search for the line "Download: 90.00 Mbit/s"
and take the 90.00 and give that to output?

---

---

**EDIT:**

for anyone interested the script I wrote down there. it outputs `<WAN_IP>,<Download>,<Upload>` and if there is no connection it outputs `0.0.0.0,0,0`

```
#!/bin/sh

SP=$(speedtest-cli 2>&1)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then

        From=$(echo "$SP" | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b")

        Down=$(echo "$SP" | gawk '{if (match($0,/Download: ([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+) Mbit\/s/,a)>0) print a[1]}')

        Up=$(echo "$SP" | gawk '{if (match ($0,/Upload: ([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+) Mbit\/s/,a)>0) print a[1]}')

else
        From="0.0.0.0"

        Down="0"

        Up="0"

fi

echo "$From,$Down,$Up"
```

Comment: echo "Download: 90.00 Mbit/s"  | awk '{print $2}'

So you can add this as last iteration.

Comment: You can do it using regex. Just match the digits

Comment: Welcome to the site. If possible, please add some example output of your `speedtest` call so it is easier to help you design a suitable regular expression.

Comment: Thank you @AdminBee . If the Speedtest gives me the Output "Download: 90.00 Mbit/s" I want to print just "90.00". I got it working with grep with a tmp file, but I would like to do that without a file. So when I tried it with the variable, grep did no longer work properly..

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I was asking for the example output is the formatting of the output. Does the relevant line start with the word `Download` immediately, or is there some indentation with leading whitespace? Does the line end immediately after the `Mbit/s`, or are there trailing characters? Are there further lines in the output that might start with `Download` or contain similar patterns? I think your problem can be solved, but that kind of information would be necessary to provide good advice.

Comment: @AdminBee Okay! I try to deliver this immediatly the next time :) So part of my Problem is, that the output in the variable doesn't really come in lines.. If I echo $SP it is just a long String. When I store the output `Download: 90.00 Mbit/s` is one line. In the variable it just in the middle of the long string with every output line

Comment: I see. The problem of unpreserved line structure can be avoided by quoting the variable as in `"$SP"`(which you should do anyway [in most cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you explicitly use `gawk`, you can use the `match()` function to look for the pattern "`Download:` number `Mbit/s`" and extract the actual value of that pattern found in your string as follows:

```
gawk '{if (match($0,/Download: ([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+) Mbit\/s/,a)>0) print a[1]}'
```

This will

- determine if the pattern was found in the first place, and
- put all `( ... )`-enclosed sub-groups of the RegExp in the elements of the array `a`

from where you can then simply use entry 1 (since there is only one such sub-group in the RegExp)
.

Comment: AWESOME! That was the solution. Thank you so much!! and Thanks for the tip with quotation of variables! I didn't know that, it's way better then using it without the quotes!

Answer (score 1):

`speedtest-cli` has a `--simple` switch which makes the output simple (try `speedtest-cli --help` for more information):

```
# speedtest-cli --simple --no-upload
Ping: 18.833 ms
Download: 33.88 Mbit/s
Upload: 0.00 Mbit/s
```

So we can get the download-only speed as a number thus:

```
# speedtest-cli --simple --no-upload|grep "^Download:"|cut -d" " -f2
34.92
```

This uses `--no-upload` to save a bit of time by not testing upload speed, `grep` to extract just the download line, and `cut` to extract the second field i.e. the number in Mbit/s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it works like that for Download and Upload speed. We want to monitor the IP Adress aswell that's why I didn't use the `--simple`. But that is my fault for not mentioning!